# Local/Global vars in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newb. I have several tables to store forms and I want the next user's input to be stored the table with the least responses (each form is different).

I've taken the rowcounts from the sql db and they are working. I use the code below detect how many responses there are and hence set $testnumber accordingly.

The code fails. Essentially, when I echo $testnumber, it doesn't matter what values the row counts are, it just randomises according to the first if statement.

When I delete the first if statement, I get an error saying that $testnumber is undefined regardless of the values of rowcounts.

I am absolutely confused the hell out. In my head the var $testnumber is local in all of the statements (they are not defined elsewhere) so they should all either work or not work.

I would appreciate some help. I know my if statements are crap and doesn't cover all cases so any help here would be useful but most IMPORTANTLY can you explain why my other statements are being ignored and why the first one isnt?

Thank you

```
if ($rowcount1 = $rowcount2 = $rowcount3 = $rowcount4){ // if all rowcounts are equal
    $testnumber = mt_rand(1,4);
}

if ($rowcount1 < $rowcount2){ //rowcount for 1 is lowest
    if($rowcount1 < $rowcount3){
        if($rowcount1 < $rowcount4){            
        $testnumber = 1;
        }
    }
};

if ($rowcount2 < $rowcount1){ // rowcount for 2 is lowest
    if($rowcount2 < $rowcount3){        
        if($rowcount2 < $rowcount4){            
        $testnumber = 2;    

        }
    }
};

if ($rowcount3 < $rowcount1){ // rowcount for 3 is lowest
    if($rowcount3 < $rowcount2){    
        if($rowcount3 < $rowcount4){    
        $testnumber = 3;    
        }
    }
};

if ($rowcount4 < $rowcount1){ //rowcount for exp2 is lowest 
    if ($rowcount4 < $rowcount2){   
        if ($rowcount4 < $rowcount3){       
        $testnumber = 4;
        }
    }
};
```

echo "Final Testnumber: " . $testnumber;

Comment: `if ($rowcount1 = $rowcount2 = $rowcount3 = $rowcount4){` << this line SETS all variables at the value of $rowcount4. you are looking for `==` instead of `=`

Comment: If you find that you're numbering variables, then you almost certainly should be using an array instead

Answer (score 3):

Your first comparison statement isn't a comparison at all: single `=` *sets* a variable, double `==` tests for equality. Thus, your conditional will always evaluate to `TRUE`, because it's setting your variables correctly.

On top of that, you need to expand out your statements, as equality comparisons don't work this way in PHP.

```
if (($rowcount1 == $rowcount2) && ($rowcount2 == $rowcount3) && ($rowcount3 == $rowcount4)){ // if all rowcounts are actaully equal
```

Check out the relevant PHP docs: [Assignment Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

---

**Edit**: Your next conditional statements are hampered by the fact that it appears you're running into issues with [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Basically, in order to access the `$testnumber` variable, you'll need to define it outside the "scope" of a conditional block.

```
$testnumber = 0;
if (($rowcount1 == ...
```

---

While outside the scope of the question: based on what you've provided here, it may be worthwhile to check out the [PHP documentation on `array`s](http://php.net/array), it will help you immensely as you start to scale your code up.

Comment: Thank you. So why doesn't the other 3 if statements work? Lets ignore the first if statement.

Comment: @razzer-bake check my edit, you may be running into issues with [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).